# Why does ltrace show so many parameters and arguments?

Tags: ltrace

It seems like ltrace is showing more parameters then the functions provide, take for instance this

```
getauxval(31, 0x7ffe5ee5a5c0, 0, 0x7066732e6d657473) = 0x7f4f747cd030
```

Why are there 4 parameters there, two integers two memory locations [rather than one parameter](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getauxval.3.html) which is all Linux's `getauxval` seems to support? What's the right way to read the output of ltrace?

Comment: Related: [How does ltrace() display rand()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131925/how-does-ltrace-display-rand). ltrace gets its info about library function arguments from various `.conf` files that ship with it, but they don't include every library function. If a function isn't found in any `.conf` file, ltrace displays exactly four arguments.

Answer (score 3):

I've stumbled upon the same question. After some research and comparison with the source file, I found out that these arguments are the values of the stack variables at the time the function is called. So If you expect (know) your function to have only 1 argument, this will be the first parameter, everything after that are the variables on the function stack